What is the true nature of an inductive definition?
First of all, there may or may not be a formal way to separate a “definition” from a “formula”, in logic.
There are two analogous concepts of “sameness”, but on different levels.
On the level of ‘terms’, or ‘things’, asserting the equivalence of two things in the formula “t1 = t2”, is generally interpreted in most semantic contexts as two things “being the same thing”. For example, consider constants James, Sally : Person, and a function brother : Person -> Person. The formula brother(Sally) = James equates two terms: the brother of Sally, and James. It states that these two things are the same thing.
On the level of ‘formulas’, or ‘propositions’, one way of conceiving of the notion of ‘logical equivalence’ is bi-implication. For example, the formula forall x, IsBritishCitizen(x) if and only if HasUKPassport(x) asserts that being a British citizen is logically equivalent to having a UK passport. It technically says that these two things will always co-occur.
An interesting aspect of both of the above “sameness declarations” is that there is not an inherent feature in first-order logic that assigns “focus” on what is being defined versus what is the definiens. If someone were to say “Robert is the King of France”, this sentence can evoke a discourse scenario in which Robert is “well-known”, except for that he is the King of France; but it could also occur in a context in which much is known about the King of France, except that it is specifically Robert.
Perhaps this teaches us that “definition” is an illusory concept; because in most cases, we may already know a bit about Robert, and a bit about the King of France, and learning they are equivalent produces many new “theorems”, or possible deductions from that knowledge. Cases where one term has “many propositions deducible about it” but another term has “none or almost no propositions deducible about it” is just a special case of establishing an equivalence, but not different from equivalences in any clearly demarcated way, though.
An inductive definition is commonly described as a definition depending on the iterated application of functions.
Yet, according to the previous considerations, it appears that all definitions, in logic, relate terms (via equality or other relations).
Thus, can there even be a formal definition of an “inductive definition”?
For example:
Here is a common definition of the natural numbers, inductively:
types:
Nat

constants:
zero : Nat

functions:
next : Nat -> Nat

This sort of “predetermines” the existence of terms like “next(next(zero))” and “next(next(next(next(zero))))”.
Here is an inductive definition of addition:
types:
Nat

constants:
zero : Nat

functions:
next : Nat -> Nat
add : Nat, Nat -> Nat

equations:
forall x : Nat, add(zero, x) = x
forall x, y : Nat, add(next(x), y) = next(add(x, y))

These appear to “generate” infinite terms through the repeated application of functions add and next.
Yet, consider: What would the alternative be? All we have, in this format, are types, constants, functions, and equations. It is impossible to assign properties or relationships to constants or types in this context without using functions, and it isn’t clear why recursive functions are characteristically different from non-recursive functions.
Should we say that any constant that appears in a formula is being “defined inductively”?
Are inductive definitions a non-concept?
Is all we really have “equivalences” rather than “definitions”?

You are conflating expressions of equality with definitions. They aren't the same thing.

You are also conflating material implication with logical implication, which is incorrect. There are several kinds of definition and the simplest kind occurs when a fresh term is introduced using a definition. In such cases, it is usually marked as such with a special symbol such as := or =df. I suppose one could also use a specific kind of Frege's judgment stroke that indicates that the sentence that follows serves as a definition. I don't see that being recursive really makes much difference.

Maybe it helps you to look at inductive definitions in a mathematical programming language like Haskell where they're called Algebraic Data Types.
There a crucial difference is made between normal functions and constructor functions. It is baked right into the syntax of the language where normal functions start with lower case and constructor functions with Upper case.
So for your Nat definition we must start with a type constructor Nat, defined as
data Nat where
     Zero : Nat
     Next : Nat -> Nat

Notes

Note the uppercase starts for Zero and Next, including Nat which is a type constructor
More crucially note the absence of any definition apart from the type specification
Zero is a 0-ary (!) constructor — what we normally call a constant.

By contrast add would be an ordinary function (lower case).
So it would have a type and defining equations
add : Nat -> Nat
add Zero     y  = y
add (Next x) y  = Next (add x y)

An evaluation of 2 + 1 would go thusly:
   add (Next (Next (Zero)) (Next Zero)
→  Next (add (Next Zero) (Next Zero))
→  Next (Next (add Zero (Next Zero)))
→  Next (Next (Next Zero))


These are some notes I got from an AI:

The concept of an "inductive definition" is not a primitive concept in
first-order logic, but a higher-level construct one can impose on
axioms.
A formal characterization of an inductive definition is a set of
axioms of the form:
(a) Base case: φ(c) for some constant c
(b) Inductive step: ∀x (φ(x) → φ(f(x))) for some function f
Where φ is a predicate symbol.

It is related to how we say a given function induces something, such as a function f: X -> Y inducing a relation < on Y. Perhaps an inductive definition is a definition based on implication: if phi(x), then psi(x), for example. There are logics that lack the implication operation, so perhaps this is a way to frame the idea as actually distinctive.
I do not know how to interpret this philosophically, though, for example, if inductive definitions are “generative”, as opposed to “non-generative definitions”. I am also unsure if it can be argued that inductive definitions generate structure in such a way that we do not need to identify a model of a theory as we do with “static” definitions; or, if the nature of inductive definitions is that we are actually using syntactic functions to generate an infinite of formulae describing the properties of a structure (a model).
If inductive definition is a “meta-logical property”, then perhaps it is formally defined in a formal language describing first-order logic; it is formulas of a certain type, using the deduction relation, \vdash. What if it was encapsulated precisely as “any formula including at least one implication operation and at least one deduction relation”, for example?
Here are further notes I gathered from AIs and edited:

Inductive definitions can be understood through the lens of fixed-point theory.
An inductive definition is specifying a monotone operator on a complete lattice of sets.
The Knaster-Tarski theorem guarantees the existence of least and greatest fixed points for such operators,
which correspond to the "minimal" set satisfying the inductive definition.
Given a monotone operator Γ on a complete lattice (L, ≤),
the least fixed point is given by:
LFP(Γ) = ⋂{X ∈ L | Γ(X) ≤ X}
In model theory, an implicit definition is one where a term or predicate is uniquely determined by a set of axioms,
even if not explicitly defined.
Beth's definability theorem establishes a connection between implicit definability and explicit definability in first-order logic.
Inductive definitions can be seen as a special case of implicit definitions,
where the defined concept is the least set (or structure) satisfying certain closure properties.
This aligns with the idea that all definitions might be viewed as "equivalences".
The proof-theoretic strength of systems allowing inductive definitions is an active area of research in mathematical logic.
Systems with unrestricted inductive definitions can exceed the strength of first-order arithmetic.
This related to the "generative" power of inductive definitions.
In standard (well-founded) set theory, inductive definitions are grounded in the axiom of foundation.
In non-well-founded set theories, such as those developed by Aczel and others, we can have "circular" or "co-inductive" definitions.
This broadens our understanding of what constitutes a "definition" in set-theoretic foundations.
Inductive definitions have a role in generating infinite structures
In type theory, particularly within Martin-Löf Type Theory and dependent type theories, inductive definitions are formalized through the introduction of inductive types.
An inductive type is defined by specifying a finite set of constructors that generate its elements.
Formally, an inductive type J can be defined as a collection of constructors, C1,…,Cn
Each Ci has a type that may involve J itself
First-order logic does not inherently support inductive definitions as type theory does, but they can be emulated using recursive definitions and axioms
For example, the Peano axioms are an inductive definition of natural numbers: Zero is in Nat, every Nat has a successor in Nat, zero is not the successor of any number, and for any property P which holds of zero, and for which P(x) implies P(succ(x)), it follows that P(x) for all x.

￼
